# Get client browser version in C# (When IE Compatibility mode enabled)

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, internet-explorer

We need to know client's browser version from C# code. We use Request.Browser or HTTP_USER_AGENT to get the details. However, In IE when compatibility mode is enabled it always returns IE 7 version irrespective of version of IE. ie, even in IE 11 when compatibility mode enabled it returns IE 7 but I want actual version which is IE 11. Is there any way I can get actual IE version?

Comment: Hi: As I mentioned before, I need the info in C# (server side) not client side.

Comment: Browser version sniffing is very much frowned upon these days.  Instead it is recommended to feature sniff.

Comment: I said server side. Not JavaScript.

Comment: Looks like your question was tagged with JS, tag spamming?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We found out the solution. HTTP_USER_AGENT will contain "Trident" value which can be used for this purpose. Each version of IE contains different Trident version values like Trident 5.0, Trident 6.0 etc., This can be used for identifying IE version.

Answer (score 1):

**I think this is best help for u.**

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

```
        var userAgent = HttpContext.Current.Request.UserAgent;
        var userBrowser = new HttpBrowserCapabilities
        {
            Capabilities = new Hashtable
            {
                {
                    string.Empty, userAgent
                }
            }
        };

        var factory = new BrowserCapabilitiesFactory();
        factory.ConfigureBrowserCapabilities(
            new NameValueCollection(), userBrowser);




        //Set User browser Properties
        var BrowserBrand = userBrowser.Browser;
        var BrowserVersion = userBrowser.Version;


        Response.Write("browser brand :- " + BrowserBrand + "<br/>");
        Response.Write("browser version :- " + BrowserVersion + "<br/>");



    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Write this below in Page_load

```
HttpBrowserCapabilities brObject = Request.Browser;

Response.Write("Browser Type: "+ brObject.Type);
Response.Write("<p>"+"Browser Version: "+ brObject.Version);
```

Comment: That's exactly what he used.

Comment: This is what is tried. But does not work for compatibility mode.

Comment: I ve tried this code and worked for me "Request.Browser.Browser "gives Internet Explorer and "Request.MajorVersion" gives 11 which is my current browser version

Comment: Did you enable compatibility mode? When you enable this then even IE 11 ,  Request.MajorVersion gives you 7 NOT 11